# Migrate nio based socket programming to Spring Web Socket

Tags: java, spring, sockets, websocket, spring-websocket

Currently we have a requirement where in , The Client and Server are Java applications that communicate with each other using Java NIO Sockets, Selectors and SocketChannel

However in our new requirement, the client is a Angular application and would like to communicate to server via Stomp based Websocket(Using Spring).

I am finding challenge in migrating some of Socket Channels to Spring based Websocket connection.

Please guide me on the appropriate approach.